# ¿Como marcar opción pulsada en menú bootstrap con jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

En otro post me pasan este código:

```
( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li").on("click", function(){
    $(".nav").find(".activa").removeClass("activa");
    $(this).addClass("activa");
  });
});

/*CSS*/
.activa{
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

pero no me funciona, no encuentro nada en google para solucionar esto.

asi tengo el menú con bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
       para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>

  <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
       otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="index.php">Biografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="discografia.php">Discografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="descargas.php">Descargas</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esta solución :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    $('.nav li a').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Fuente : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4866848