# Cómo modificar una expresión regular para evitar añadir una clase a todos los <li> del menú

Tags: jquery, html5, regex

En un menú bootstrap.

```js
 var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    $('.nav li a').each(function()
    {
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,'')))
        {
         
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('activa');
        }
    });
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.activa{
 background-color:red;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
         para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
         otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Biografía</a></li>
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Discografía</a></li>
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Descargas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

con la siguiente función le añado una clase para marcar la opción del menú activa.

```js
var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    $('.nav li a').each(function()
    {
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,'')))
        {

            $(this).parent('li').addClass('activa');
        }
    });
```

y funciona bien en producción, pero al cargar la página en mi ambiente local, en la url `localhost/mono`, aparecen todos los `li` del menú con la clase agregada.

¿Cómo modificar la expresión regular e indicar que al cargar la página por defecto se marque con la clase activa el `index.php`?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. "*al cargar la página aparecen todos con la clase agregada*" <--- No, sólo 1 de esos podría tener la clase... Esa expresión regular tiene algunos problemas pero lo que intenta hacer no es marcar la opción activa, sino marcar la url que coincide con la ubicación actual

Comment: @Rafael podrías explicar qué estás intentando hacer? Si sólo te interesa marcar el `index.php`, marcalo en el html, no hace falta hacerlo por código JavaScript.

Comment: el codigo me funciona. a medias. con él al seleccionar una opcion del menú esta queda marcada. pero si entro en la web cargando el index.php todas las opciones del menú cogen los estilos de la clase .activa

Comment: Quizá esta respuesta pueda ayudarte. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30490/como-marcar-opci%C3%B3n-pulsada-en-men%C3%BA-bootstrap-con-jquery/30492#30492

Comment: @Dev.Joel esa respuesta es la que está publicando como pregunta, ya que le trajo problemas

Comment: @Mariano es muy raro que dé problemas. el error debe ser de otra parte del código del OP.

Comment: @Dev.Joel No es raro. Yo le veo algunos problemas. Por ejemplo, si `window.location.pathname == "/"` coincidiría con todas las páginas. Si la url del link coincidiera con el dominio, también marcaría mal. El regex podría no compilar en algunos casos más raros... En fin, le veo varios problemas

Comment: @Dev.Joel que sea una respuesta muy votada en SO no significa que esté bien :-)

Comment: Funciona perfectamente para mi. Para el OP que formulo la pregunta de mi enlace también , falto remover la clase active para los demás li en mi respuesta.  @RafaelHernández dentro del if `$('.nav li').removeClass('active');` falta esa línea.

Comment: @Dev.Joel El OP que formuló esa pregunta es el mismo que está preguntando ahora.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión regular que estás usando no está bien construida y podría seleccionar elementos no deseados (aunque no es el caso actual). Además, ese código selecciona el path actual, pero no necesariamente a `index.php` cuando es la página por defecto.

Para solucionarlo, expandimos todas las URLs para que, si terminan en `/`, o si la última parte de la url no tiene un punto, se le agregue `index.php`.

**Código:**

```js
var paginaDefault = 'index.php',
    urlActual = window.location.href.replace(/(\/[^./]+)$|\/$/,'$1/' + paginaDefault);
    
$(".nav li a").each(function(){
    if (this.href.replace(/(\/[^./]+)$|\/$/,'$1/' + paginaDefault) == urlActual) {
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('activa');
    }
});
```

```css
.activa, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.activa>a {
    /* marcamos en rojo */
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery y bootstrap -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- HTML -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
       para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>

  <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
       otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="currentindex" class="linkmenu"><a href="index.php">Biografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="/js">Página Actual</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="/discografia.php">Discografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="descargas.php">Descargas</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Expresión regular en: https://regex101.com/r/1Zxu1z/2

Comment: no me sirve tu código @Mariano. haber cuando introduzco localhost/mono se produce el error. todos los li del menú quedan marcados por .activa, luego hago click en biografia (index.php) y se marca bien y los demas tambien pero como marco por defecto index.php? al entrar en la web? por que poner una clase o id especifica al li biografia no me sirve....

Comment: @Rafael Si todos los `li` tienen la clase, significa que lo estás agregando de otro lado del código. Como verás, en este ejemplo funciona, por lo que el problema está en algún otro lugar. ¿A qué te referís con que quedan todos marcados? Podrías publicar un ejemplo que lo reproduzca?

Comment: www.jamondemono.com

Comment: @Rafael Ya vi cual es el problema: estás usando `window.location.pathname`, que devuelve un valor vacío en el root... La pregunta es ¿qué te interesa marcar como `.activa`? ¿Sólo a index.php, a  la página actual? ¿A qué?

Comment: me interesa marcar como .activa el index.php al cargar la web. luego pasar la clase .activa entre las opciones del menú

Comment: @Rafael Es decir, marcar sólo como activa a la página en la que está actualmente?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47739/discussion-between-rafael-hernandez-and-mariano).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle un id a cada elemento del menú y directamente en el html, en cada vista, agregar una etiqueta `<style>` dandole estilo al elemento con el id que corresponda.

Answer (score 0):

Por que no utilizas el local storage para poder establecer el link que deseas:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentSection', 'pagina');
```

Tendrías que cambiar tus `href` por `onclick` y poder tener una mejor manipulación de tus urls (claro esto desde mi punto de vista)

También para que pueda funcionar lo siguiente tendrás que agregar una clase única que haga referencia a tu localstorage que guardas.

Deberás tomar en cuenta que cada que le den click a un menu esta variable cambiaría (la del localStorage).

La parte de la magia sucede aquí:

```
li {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.active {
  background: cyan !important;
  color: magenta !important;
}
```

Y simplemente comparas

```
if (localStorage.getItem('currentSection') === 'currentLink') {
  document.querySelector('.currentLink').classList.add('active');
}
```

Esto funciona solamente si se recarga la página, de lo contrarío tendrías mas de un elemento con el mismo estilo.