# Por qué no se aplica mi clase active a mi NavBar - JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy haciendo una página y no se aplica la clase active del todo, vuelve la clase active al que está por defecto ,  ¿por qué pasa esto?  Este es el `link` de la página [llanes](https://dev.omb.cloud/yllanes/index)

Este es el código, pero aquí si se me ejecuta

```js
$(function() {
            // elementos de la lista
            var menues = $("#navbarSupportedContent .navbar-nav .nav-item"); 
                // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
                menues.click(function() {
                    // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
                    menues.removeClass("active");
                    // activamos el elemento clicado.
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                });
        });
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
 color: #000;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--     BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN -->
    <div class="container-fluid  p-1 sticky-top" style="background: #F6F6F6;">
     <div class="container" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background: #F6F6F6;">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index"><img src="img/yllanes/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="width: 150px;"></a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quienes Somos</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Semblanza</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios Jurídicos</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Noticias</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contácto</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
<!-- FIN DE BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image: img]

Comment: Para añadir la clase active, deberías comparar con la ruta actual, los listener no funcionan para este caso, ya que al cambiar de página esto queda invalidado. [Como ejemplo base](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30490/como-marcar-opci%C3%B3n-pulsada-en-men%C3%BA-bootstrap-con-jquery/30492#30492)

Comment: y como hago eso?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas apuntar al `item` que tiene la clase active, en este caso es `nav-item`, y ya con eso debería de eliminar el actual y aplicarle el active al nuevo.

```js
$(function() {
            // elementos de la lista
            var menues = $(".nav-item"); 
                // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
                menues.click(function() {
                    // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
                    menues.removeClass("active");
                    // activamos el elemento clicado.
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                });
        });
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
 color: #000;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--     BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN -->
    <div class="container-fluid  p-1 sticky-top" style="background: #F6F6F6;">
     <div class="container" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background: #F6F6F6;">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index"><img src="img/yllanes/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="width: 150px;"></a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quienes Somos</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Semblanza</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios Jurídicos</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Noticias</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contácto</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
<!-- FIN DE BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: _hola_ ya lo intente y el estilo se resetea https://dev.omb.cloud/yllanes/nosotros

Comment: Ha que te refieres con que el estilo se resetea?

Comment: vuelve a estar en negrita el elemento que puse active por defecto